# How can i change my username on the meta site?

Tags: support, meta

I would like to know, on the main Stack Exchange overview I would like to know is it possible to change my username? I don't like the current one right now and I would like to know if I could find a way to change it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about *this* site, Meta Stack Exchange, then all you need to do is go [to your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/275332/lego-bug), click "edit", and set your display name to whatever you want.

If you're talking about any other meta site in the network, you have to edit your display name on the actual Q&A site that meta's attached to (that is, for RolePlaying Games meta, you should edit your profile on Roleplaying Games).

You can also apply your changes to all Stack Exchange sites if you'd rather not have different display names on different sites.

Comment: Will users be able to click on that subsite in my profile and see my (different) username? Or is that "new" profile shielded from my usual username? For instance, when I click on your username right now, I can browse into your contributions to music: practice and theory.  I want people to not find out what I'm doing in the workplace subsite. :O

Comment: @neuronet You should assume that yes, it's possible.

Comment: The OP asked about their *username*, not their display name.

Comment: @CarlSmith We don't have another definition of username.

Comment: We have a username, like on any site, and a display name too. Changing the display name is easy, but getting a new username is more involved.

Comment: @CarlSmith Okay, what do you think is the "username" around here? If you are talking about the email address you use to log in using Stack Exchange OpenID... sure. I suppose you could refer to that as the username. Or are you talking about the user id? Either way, the latter can't be changed and the former isn't something you change on "meta sites".

Comment: You can create a new account, then merge them. Personally, I came here looking specifically for the FAQ, How to Change Your Username.

Comment: @CarlSmith Lower userid persists on merges (or at least it should in 99% of cases), so merging won't really change anything.

Comment: That's interesting. I thought the most recent account would persist. To keep the old one defeats the purpose. Sites like SO should let people use their real names, which can change. This is not a good place to discuss it though. Best.

Comment: @CarlSmith I have a feeling we may be talking past each other a little bit. Still not 100% sure what you're trying to change here. A new meta post would be a great place to describe that, if you feel like it. :)